# How to get an ID from url without using "?id=" in route config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, config

There are lots of questions on this but none that clarifies this specific scenario.

I want to make an URL that has nothing to do with the controller or action name, and I want the ID value to be put there directly (not with `"?id="`).

Meaning I want the following URL:

```
http://localhost/word/43
```

To call the action "whatever" in controller "nevermind" with the id "43".

in route config I have :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "yes",
    url: "word/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "nevermind", action = "whatever"},
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

If I enter the URL `localhost/word?id=43` it works fine, if I enter the URL i want, which is `localhost/word/43`, it doesn't work, the id comes up as null .

The controller method is

```
public ActionResult whatever(int id)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Please update your post to include the source code for the `whatever` action.

Comment: You need to show the signature of your controller method - if its `public ActionResult whatever(int id)`, and you route is before the default route (or any other matching routes), then you code works fine

Comment: @StephenMuecke It has to be with `Request.Params`, that is why he's getting a null value. Otherwise, he would have gotten an exception. See my answer below.

Comment: @KobyDouek,  `Request.Params` have nothing to do with it. Its a route definition

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's exactly what I'm saying... Did you read my answer? He used `Request.Params` and now he's using routing, that's why he's getting the null value.

Comment: @KobyDouek, Nowhere has OP mentioned anything about using `Request.Params`. The code OP has shown works fine using `.../word/43`, and the value of the `id` parameter in the method will be `43`, assuming that route definition is before any other matching routes

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right. The only reason this wouldn't be working is if there's a route before this one that's matching instead. Post your entire RouteConfig.cs.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's the first route. :(

Comment: @KobyDouek He is right, I didn't use Request.Params anywhere...

Comment: Then what are you claiming is not working? (you have said _the id comes up as null_ but that is impossible - the parameter is typeof `int` which can never be `null`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke here is my exact error: 
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult whatever(Int32)'

Comment: If its the first route, then what your claiming does not make sense. There must be something else causing the issue

Comment: I guess I'll just change the link to /word?=43 although I wanted to avoid this somehow. :( 
Thanks for the help attempt.

Comment: How can the id come up as null? it of type int which can't be null.

Comment: What is the name of the class in which `whatever` lives?

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YourController : Controller
{
    HttpPost("{id}")
    public IActionResult YorMethod(int id)
    {

    }
}
```

Then in your request:
http://localhost:5166/api/YourController/YorMethod/2